# View C Documentation within VSCode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, manual

During my workflow, I frequently have to switch from the VSCode window to a terminal in order to pull up a man page on stdlib function or similar. I'm looking for a way to cut down the on the inefficiency of this process. This would seem to be a very common and useful need, but I'm surprised that I wasn't able to find a solution by searching for C documentation in VSCode.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how this or a suitable alternative might work as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Cpp Reference and Documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FederAndInk.cpp-reference-and-documentation) extension. [Search StackOverflow](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=parvezmrobin.search-stackoverflow) may also be useful

Or if you prefer to use a terminal then just use the [integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal). No need to switch to another app, only a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>